# "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pdf2image'"

Tags: aws-lambda, python-packaging, aws-lambda-layers

I have been working on Lambda to convert pdf to png and using the pdf2image library to create a layer for my Lambda. I tried in many different ways but seems it doesn't work for me.

"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'pdf2image'",
"errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"

I would appreciate your help!

Thanks

Comment: We would need to see some code and configuration to be able to help. Please have a look at [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to include the "pdf2image" library for your lambdas to reference. To make a layer, you would need to create a directory structure that contains that code, then zip the entire directory. It may be as follows:

```
/python
    /pdf2image
        __init__.py
        pdf2image.py
        ...
```

When zipped, the zip file must have the "python" folder and inside of that you put your code. If you do this and also install your common code as a package, you can import it in your local code and in your lambdas using the same import.

What I do is use pip install to install to a certain file location--the location that I then zip into a layer. For example, if I wanted to make a layer for the pdf2image library I might do

```
pip install --target=c:\myLayers\python pdf2image
```

That will install the library files into the location I specified, which makes it easy to know what to zip up (just create a zip that includes the "python" directory).

Then of course be sure you reference the layer (by specific version) in your lambda.

Comment: Thank you! This is working but now I have different issues,   "errorMessage": "Unable to get page count. Is poppler installed and in PATH?",
  "errorType": "PDFInfoNotInstalledError"

Comment: You may want to make a new question for this new issue and post the full details.  If my response answered your original post, you can click the checkmark option to accept it.